# Perl: how to split string without storing into array and continue split?

Tags: perl, split, temporary

I guess this has been asked before, but I can't find it.

Say

```
my $string = "something_like:this-and/that";
my @w1 = split(/_/, $string);
my @w2 = split(/-/, $w1[1]);
my @w3 = split(/:/, $w2[0]);
print $w3[1]; #print out "this"
```

Is there anyway to avoid the temporary array variables @w1, @w2 and @w3 and get $w3[1] directly? I remember continue split works, but forget the syntax.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible, but would be much harder to read, so isn't advised:

```
my $string = "something_like:this-and/that";
my $this = (split /:/, (split /-/, (split(/_/, $string))[1])[0])[1];
print $this; #print out "this"
```

Alternatively, you could use a regex in this instance, but don't think it adds anything:

```
my $string = "something_like:this-and/that";
my ($this) = $string =~ /.*?_.*?:([^-]*)/ or warn "not found";
print $this;
```

Comment: Got it. I missed a pair of (). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your own solution unnecessarily splits on underscores, unless your real data is significantly different from your example. You could write this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "something_like:this-and/that";
my $value = (split /-/, (split /:/, $string)[1])[0];
print $value;
```

Or this solution uses regular expressions and does what you ask

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "something_like:this-and/that";
my ($value) = $string =~ /:([^_-]*)/;
print $value;
```

**output**

```
this
```

Comment: Given the OP's string is obviously fake data, I believe both your solutions assume too much.  Technically `$value = (split /[-:]/, $string)[1];` would also work for that exact data, but I'd not advise it.

Answer (score 0):

This will modify `$string` in place:

```
my $string = "something_like:this-and/that";
$string =~ s/^.*:(.+)-.*/$1/;
```

Comment: That leaves `$string` set to `_like:this-and/that`